# How to replace all types of strings meta/alphanumeric/ using Perl or shell

Tags: regex, string, perl, shell, metacharacters

```
sed -i 's/'$search'/'$replace'/g' $file
```

this command is able to replace only strings..but i wanted to search and replace any kind of strings in a file

Ex : if i give input

```
 $search= /jms/CodeBasev1.23*
 $replace= /jms/CodeBasev1.24/baseline*.
```

it should search for exact string and replace the exact line .. Not only with slashes but also it should accept meta-characters also

ex: [..],%,&,() ..etc

Comment: Someone please edit this...

Comment: Edited a bit but still the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -0777 -pi -e's/\Q$ENV{search}/$ENV{replace}/g' $file
```

`-0777` is only necessary if the search string contains literal newlines.